# Reg-Ex decimal number with two places

Tags: regex, validation

Can someone help me out with reg-ex for a decimal number with two places. it must have two places after the .

So

2.1 - Fail

2 - fail

786 - fail

---

786.00 - pass

2.00 pass

10.10- pass

Comment: i recommend you follow one or two tutorials for learning regex yourself. it is not hard to learn, and will help you a lot in your future coding life. plus it makes you happy whenever you see a regex and know you can understand it, instead of frustrated. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use anchors in your regex.

```
^\d+\.\d{2}$
```

Anchors helps to do an exact match so it won't match numbers like `45.678`

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
\d+\.\d{2}
```

[DEMO HERE](https://regex101.com/r/gZ2jB8/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
^[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}$
```

explanation:
`[0-9]+` any digit -> must be atleast 1 digit 
. -> a must . 
`[0-9]{2}` -> must be exactly 2 digits